# Как склонировать без папки проекта?

Tags: git

Понимаю, что надо в конце точку ставить, но не не выходит! Всегда клонируется с папкой проекта! Может что-то еще надо?

Варианты как пробовал:

1. git clone _______.git .
2. git clone _______.git ./
3. git clone _______.git

UPD:

Папка куда клонирую - пустая.

Comment: видимо в репе папка в папке. т.к. точка должна была помочь

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, а никак нельзя ее из папки репы выкатить? При клонировании

Comment: Или придется перемещать все файлы наверх вручную?

Comment: Какая у вас ОС? Не очень понял, в чем ваша проблема. Попробовал в linux, `mkdir test`, `cd test`, `git clone <repository> .`, проект склонировался в директорию `test`.

Comment: Обычная Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: В само'м проекте эта папка и находится. Если вы файлы из папки переместите, то будет полностью изменён проект.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-общем, разобрался. Оказывается по умолчанию клонируется и ставится ветка "main". А я смотрел на ветку "master". Поэтому и не мог понять откуда появляется верхняя папка.

Решение проблемы было следующее: при клонировании явно указать переключение ветки:

```
git clone --branch=BRANCH_NAME ____________.git .
```